# R data.frame ; get range of values in column

Tags: r, aggregate

I cannot figure out how to do this. I have a data.frame in R. It looks like this:

```
Scores <- read.table(text = "
        ID Test1 Test2 Test3 Final
1 Student1    20    23    21    48
2 Student2    16    15    18    36
3 Student3    25    20    22    40
4 Student4    14    19    18    42
5 Student5    10    15    14    30
")
```

What I want is to create a new data object that has the range of values for each test, including the final. So it will look something like this:

```
result <- read.table(text = "
       min max
Test1  10  25
Test2  15  23
Test3  14  22
Final  30  48
")
```

It honestly doesn't matter to me whether it just lists the max and min values, or actually calculate the difference. I just can't figure out a way to implement this that isn't unnecessarily complicated. I know I can pull the columns out manually and individually, but there must be some better way of doing this. Something involving `by()` or `tapply()`? But I just cannot get them to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like this is your first [r] question on StackOverflow. Welcome! Please see here about [making a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610) as a guide to help us answer your questions in this and future posts.

Comment: Oh, okay! I will use that for future reference. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, reproducible example included.

```
test <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(2,3,5),d=c(1,2,2))
data.frame(min=sapply(test,min),max=sapply(test,max))
```

EDIT: Adding to @Blue Magister request for reproducible example: Look into `?dput` `?structure` to figure out how to post your `data.frame` here, e.g: dput(scores).

Comment: Okay, thanks for helping! Fiddling around it seems like all I have to do then is use indexing (i.e. test[,i]) to get specific columns or ranges of them. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10):

A bit simpler:

```
> t(sapply(test, range))
  [,1] [,2]
a    1    3
b    2    5
d    1    2
```

Comment: Need to find a range, use `range()` - seems the most sensible option to me.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without getting duplicate values in the range?

Comment: @MichaelPerdue you mean like if the min and max of a range are the same number?

Comment: @SenorO: if you only want unique values in your output.

Comment: @MichaelPerdue That's a different question. Search the site for how to remove duplicate rows in a data frame.

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(1)
scores <- data.frame(ID=paste0("Student",1:5),
                     T1=sample(100,5),
                     T2=sample(100,5),
                     T3=sample(100,5),
                     Final=sample(100,5))

summ <- data.frame(min=apply(scores[,!grepl("ID",colnames(scores))],2,min),
                   max=apply(scores[,!grepl("ID",colnames(scores))],2,max))

> summ
      min max
T1     20  89
T2      6  94
T3     18  74
Final  37  98
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
kk<-Map(function(x) cbind(x,min=min(Scores[,x]),max=max(Scores[,x])), as.list(names(Scores)[-1]))
data.frame(do.call(rbind,kk))
      x min max
1 Test1  10  25
2 Test2  15  23
3 Test3  14  22
4 Final  30  48
```

Answer (score 0):

(r_dd <- range(rdu_flights[5])), 
here rdu_flights is my data frame, [5] is the index number (you can find by using names("rdu_flights"), r_dd is the variable I am calling the range. I think this is pretty simple. 
I got the result as 
[1] -17 293  # represents the min and max values for departure delay of certain flights

Answer (score 0):

```
colrange<-function(x){
    sapply(x,range)
}
```

Make a `colrange` fucntion and insert your data: `colrange(scores)`